# Realigning labels and levels in multi-level columns in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

Based on an example DataFrame with multi-level columns that I found on another question:

```
arrays = [[1, 2]*3, ['A', 'B', 'C']*2]
columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(arrays, names=['foo', 'bar'])
​
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(2,6),
                  columns=columns,
                  index= pd.date_range('20000103',periods=2))
print(df)

foo                1         2         1         2         1         2
bar                A         B         C         A         B         C
2000-01-03  2.040867 -1.727071  0.126223  2.101799  1.811349 -0.003293
2000-01-04 -2.644979  0.156852 -1.034756  0.609625 -0.213968 -0.293759
```

I need to re-order column labels to instead follow this pattern, re-aligning the data as necessary:

```
bar                A         A         B         B         C         C
foo                1         2         1         2         1         2
2000-01-03  2.040867  2.101799  1.811349 -1.727071  0.126223 -0.003293
2000-01-04 -2.644979  0.609625 -0.213968  0.156852 -1.034756 -0.293759
```

I swapped the column levels with either of these:

```
 # option one
 df.columns = df.columns.reorder_levels([1,0])

 # option two
 df.columns = df.columns.swaplevel(0, 1)
```

This worked, but how do I go about moving the labels around while keeping the data aligned?

I tried the following:

```
df.columns = df.columns.set_labels([0,0,1,1,2,2], level=0).set_labels([0,1,0,1,0,1], level=1)
```

Unfortunately the data does not move with the labels (i.e. data is now misaligned):

```
bar                A                   B                   C          
foo                1         2         1         2         1         2
2000-01-03  2.040867 -1.727071  0.126223  2.101799  1.811349 -0.003293
2000-01-04 -2.644979  0.156852 -1.034756  0.609625 -0.213968 -0.293759
```

I have many things, including reindexing, to no avail.

---

**EDIT:** This was just an figurative example but in reality my data contains categorical labels [Min, Max, Single] in the second level of the column axis (after the swap), i.e.:

```
arrays = [['Max', 'Min', 'Single']*3, np.repeat(['A', 'B', 'C'], 3)]
columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(arrays, names=['foo', 'bar'])
​
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(2,9),
                  columns=columns,
                  index= pd.date_range('20000103',periods=2))
print(df)
​
foo              Max       Min    Single       Max       Min    Single       Max       Min    Single
bar                A         A         A         B         B         B         C         C         C
2000-01-03 -0.004233  0.820975  1.481674  0.064850 -0.178978 -0.862092  0.136279 -0.517081 -1.557611
2000-01-04  0.835346 -0.403773 -0.035985  1.079355  1.780113 -1.037420  1.459070 -0.254668 -0.091501

df.columns = df.columns.swaplevel(0,1)
​
print(df)

bar                A                             B                             C                    
foo              Max       Min    Single       Max       Min    Single       Max       Min    Single
2000-01-03 -0.004233  0.820975  1.481674  0.064850 -0.178978 -0.862092  0.136279 -0.517081 -1.557611
2000-01-04  0.835346 -0.403773 -0.035985  1.079355  1.780113 -1.037420  1.459070 -0.254668 -0.091501
```

For the second level, I want to use an explicitly provided order: `['Min', 'Max', 'Single']`. Therefore, sorting alphabetically as suggested by @Primer will not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you have swapped the levels you need to use `.sort_index` and this will produce desired result.
This works for me:

```
arrays = [[1, 2]*3, ['A', 'B', 'C']*2]
columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(arrays, names=['foo', 'bar'])

df = pd.DataFrame(pd.np.random.randn(2,6),
                  columns=columns,
                  index= pd.date_range('20000103',periods=2))
print(df)

foo             1      2      1      2      1      2
bar             A      B      C      A      B      C
2000-01-03 -1.165  0.901  0.466 -1.536  1.488  1.896
2000-01-04  1.179 -0.180 -1.071  1.054 -0.403  1.222

df.columns = df.columns.swaplevel(0, 1)
df.sort_index(1, inplace=True)
print df

bar             A             B             C       
foo             1      2      1      2      1      2
2000-01-03 -1.165 -1.536  1.488  0.901  0.466  1.896
2000-01-04  1.179  1.054 -0.403 -0.180 -1.071  1.222
```

**UPDATE**:

`Categorical` has `ordered` attribute which you can use to setup any order you want and then sort it with `.sort_index` or `.sort`.
Here is an illustration of how to setup custom order for `foo`:

```
array1 = ['A', 'B']*3
array2 = ['Min', 'Max', 'Single']*2
columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(zip(array2, array1), names=['foo', 'bar'])

df = pd.DataFrame(pd.np.random.randn(2,6),
                  columns=columns,
                  index= pd.date_range('20000103',periods=2))

print df

foo        Single    Max    Min Single    Max    Min
bar             A      B      A      B      A      B
2000-01-03  0.098  0.583 -0.399  0.370 -1.307  1.658
2000-01-04 -0.118 -0.680  0.666 -0.461 -1.334 -1.347

# Here is we extract foo column just to illustrate that it is Categorical and sorted in 'wrong' order:
df = df.stack().stack().reset_index().rename(columns={'level_0':'date',0:'val'})
df['foo'] = df.foo.astype('category')
print df.foo

0        Max
1        Min
2     Single
3        Max
4        Min
5     Single
6        Max
7        Min
8     Single
9        Max
10       Min
11    Single
Name: foo, dtype: category
Categories (3, object): [Max, Min, Single]
```

Note the list in the last line - this is the order (alphabetical) it will get sorted if you call `.sort` on it.

Now we will redefine this column with the new order:

```
df['foo'] = pd.Categorical(pd.np.asarray(df.foo), categories=['Min','Single','Max'], ordered=True)
print df.foo

0        Max
1        Min
2     Single
3        Max
4        Min
5     Single
6        Max
7        Min
8     Single
9        Max
10       Min
11    Single
Name: foo, dtype: category
Categories (3, object): [Min < Single < Max]
```

Note in the last line the list now is showing a new order and `<` signs are telling that this is an `ordered` `Categorical` series.
It will be sorted in the shown order when you call `.sort` on it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. I have edited the my question to include further information. In reality the second level of my column index is categorical and cannot be sorted alphabetically or numerically. I need to specify an explicit order. Thanks.

Comment: It really does help. My missing link was Pandas' Categorical ;-) Thanks.